# Convert Python string in a form of a list to a list

Tags: python, list

I have a the following string in Python:

```
x = "['good', 'bad', 'something', 'another']"
```

And I want to convert it into a list `y`, such that y[0] would give me `good`, and y[1] would give me `bad`.

I tried many ways such as creating a for loop and trying x[0] or x[0][0], but all I reached was the first char, not the whole word. I also tried:

```
y = list(x)
```

But no help.

Is there a way to do it on Python?

Comment: Use the ast module...`ast.literal_eval(x)`

Comment: @Rakesh Any way to do it without extra modules?

Comment: You can use `eval` without extra modules, but as a rule, this is less safe.

Comment: What you are looking for is called **a parser**. In order to get one you need to know the rules governing the underlying string. Where did you get it from? Is that a syntax for Python lists? In that case you can use the built-in `ast` module. Without more info all answers are just shots in the dark. Because, you know, `y = ['good', 'bad', 'something', 'another']` is a proper answer as well. And how are we supposed to know what is the general form of that string?

Comment: @freakish I don't think any of this is relevant. Other people were able to provide answers and there's no more info to provide. I just have the string and would like to convert it to a list.

Comment: @Madno You don't find this relevant? And there is no more info? Amusing, so let me give you my answer: `y = ['good', 'bad', 'something', 'another']`. You had a string, now you have a list. Faster and easier to understand then any other.

Comment: @Rakesh Good, but I don't like your answer, which is why I won't accept it.

Comment: `ast` is a built in module. Why wouldn't you use it?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I just wanted a Pythonic way of doing the job, without need to import anything for a line or two (because I won't use ast anywhere else in my program).

Comment: `ast.literal_eval` is the Pythonic way of safely parsing something generated with e.g. `repr`. Certainly not generating a bunch of intermediate strings that don't care if your input is structurally relevant.

Comment: That *is* the Pythonic way. It's a part of the standard library - how much more Pythonic can you get? It's already installed, it doesn't matter if you don't use it anywhere else.

Comment: I wonder where this idea that avoiding the *standard* library is Pythonic comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using any modules. Use `str.strip` to remove brackets and then use `str.split`

**Ex:**

```
x = "['good', 'bad', 'something', 'another']"
x = map(str.strip, x.strip("[]").replace("'", "").split(","))
```

**Output:**

```
['good', 'bad', 'something', 'another']
```

Comment: This works well for the example given but fails if any of the little strings contains a comma.

Answer (score 3):

use `ast` module

```
>>> import ast
>>> y = ast.literal_eval(x)
['good', 'bad', 'something', 'another']
```

Comment: Should perhaps note that this applies for Python literals; depending on string contents, it might produce other types than a list, but it won't have arbitrary side effects.

Answer (score 1):

```
x = eval("['good', 'bad', 'something', 'another']")
```

The eval command does just that, but please avoid using it if you are not sure of what you are doing.

If, for example, you try to put runnable code inside that string, the eval command will run it, potentially disrupting your system or opening it to external attacks. I assumed that you were working on a toy script that doesn't involve networking or access from external sources

Comment: Using `eval` is a bad practice, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice

Comment: `'eval(compile("import sys;print(\'This is my program now!\');sys.exit(1)", "", "exec"))'` works great with this approach.

Comment: @HitLuca you might be ok to let any script kiddie take control of your system, but most of us would rather avoid such issues. Would you be kind enough to either edit your post to explain why one should NEVER use this solution, or just plain remove your post ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use string build in function

```
 x = "['good', 'bad', 'something', 'another']"  
 y = x.replace("\"", "").replace("[", "").replace("]","").replace("'", "").split(',')
```

You will get result:
`y[0]` as `good`